# 20.04 Alert Volume slider missing

Tags: sound, settings

In previous versions I was able to change volume of system alert so it is not playing on full power of my speakers with slider like this:

[image: previous settings image]

But this is not possible in system settings anymore. Is there any way to change this setting from console?

Comment: I'm not a GNOME user, but in the mean time I'd use `pavucontrol` to adjust the volume of *System Sounds*  (it might be that's what you need to do, but you may get a better suggestion from a GNOME user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not found a way to change this from command line but as @guiverc suggested I was able to lower system sounds volume using `pavucontrol`:

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Playback -> System Sounds

And it does not affect other applications volume so works perfect.